# Deezer Android SDK 0.10.17 Beta Facebook authentication error

Tags: android, deezer

I switched from Deezer Android SDK 0.10.16 to 0.10.17 Beta and now every time I try to authenticate using a Facebook account, I'm redirected to a webview with the following error:

> ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

The address the browser tries to reach is:

> dzconnect://MYPACKAGE/success#access_token=...&expires=...

I haven't changed anything in my code, just updated SDK.

This is my login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
    protected static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"basic_access", "manage_library", "delete_library", "listening_history", "manage_community"};

    // DeezerConnect object
    private DeezerConnect   m_deezerConnect;

    // Handle connection callbacks.
    private DialogHandler   m_dialogHandler     = new DialogHandler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        m_deezerConnect = new DeezerConnect(getString(R.string.deezer_app_id));

        SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();

        ...

        connectToDeezer(m_dialogHandler);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to Deezer web services using an injectable DialogListener listener.
     * @param listener event listener that will be notified of the connection progress.
     */
    private void connectToDeezer(final DialogListener listener)
    {
        m_deezerConnect.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, listener);
    }

    /** Handle DeezerConnect callbacks. */
    private class DialogHandler implements DialogListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final Bundle values)
        {
            SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
            sessionStore.save(m_deezerConnect, LoginActivity.this);

            ...

            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e)
        {
            ...
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the 0.10.17 is still in beta, we'll take a look into this issue, meanwhile you can keep using the 0.10.16 version

Comment: Ok, I can try test versions if you want.